# A user should only be able to pay a registration that was made by him

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/payment/registration/{registrationID}', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@payment',
    'as'   =>'conferences.payment'
]);
```

When the user accesses this route through "`http://proj.test/conference/2/conference-title/payment/registration/1`" it appears a multi step form so the user can enter some data to pay the registration that he did in a conference.

It is working fine, when the user accesses "`http://proj.test/conference/2/conference-title/payment/registration/1`" it appears the multi step form.

The issue is that for example if another user, with a different id in the users table, he can also access "`http://proj.test/conference/2/title/payment/registration/1`" and pay the same registration with id "1" that belongs to another user.

So any user can pay any registration, but a user should only be able to pay a registration that was made by him.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

PaymentController:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    public function payment($id, $slug, $regID)
    {

        $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
            'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
                $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
            }
        ])->find($regID);

        $registrationTypes = [];


        return view('conferences.payment', compact('registrationTypeDetails', 'id', 'slug'));
    }
}
```

$registrationTypeDetails shows:

```
Registration {#259 ▼
...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#263 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Participant {#270 ▼
         ...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#276 ▼
              ....
              #attributes: array:12 [▼
                "id" => 2
                "name" => "free"
                "price" => 0
                "conference_id" => 2
              ]
              ...
            }
          ]
         ...
        }
        1 => Participant {#272 ▼
          ...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#278 ▼
            ...
              #attributes: array:12 [▼
                "id" => 3
                "name" => "paid"
                "price" => 1
                "conference_id," => 2
              ]
             ...
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
...
}
```

Comment: show me your PaymentController@payment function please

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with that.

Comment: Can you post your table structure ?

Comment: The structure of which table? Registrations table? Registrations: id, status, conference_id, main_participant_id.

Comment: @johnW main_participant_id is the id of users table ?

Comment: Yes, and is the id of the user that did the registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Laravel Authentication system, you can get the current authenticated user and check if his ID matches the user_id on the registration. I'm assuming there's a relationship between the user and the registration created by him, if not, there should be.

It will be something like this:

```
use Auth;
// ...all your other imports

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    public function payment($id, $slug, $regID)
    {
        // get the current user
        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
            'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
                $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
            }
        ])->find($regID);

        // check if the user id matches
        if ($registrationTypeDetails->main_participant_id != $user_id) {
            // user didn't create this registration
            // ...do whatever you need to
        }
        else {
            $registrationTypes = [];

            return view('conferences.payment', compact('registrationTypeDetails', 'id', 'slug'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears "Trying to get property of non-object
" in "        if ($registrationTypeDetails->user_id != $user->id) {
".

Comment: well, that's weird. Does the code return the expected result without that if?

Comment: are you using Laravel's php artisan make:auth?

Comment: In the registrations table the column is not user_id is main_participant_id I dont know if that can be the issue.

Comment: I updated the question with the result of $registrationTypeDetails.

Comment: that's probably it, use the 'main_participant_id'. Check my edits.

Comment: Thanks but same error Trying to get property of non-object
.

Comment: Maybe the issue that is with "$user->id", to use that is necessary to have "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
" or is another?

Comment: Sorry, the user was not loged in!! Thanks!